# Searching user page with telephone number facebook using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

My purpose is to find page(url/id) having telephone(mobile) number. I tried to do something like:

```
query=phone_number
r=requests.get("https://graph.facebook.com/search?access_token=" + token +  "&q=" + query + "&type=user")
```

Every time I got error  :"Application does not have the capability to make this API call".

Is it forbidden to search with telephone, or I'm making mistake?
My code:

```
import requests
import facebook
token ="Here is my token"
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
query=str(375293253273)
r=requests.get("https://graph.facebook.com/search?access_token=" + token +  "&q=" + query + "&type=user")
print(r.text)
op=graph.request('search', {'q': '375293253273', 'type': 'user'})
print(op)
```

Comment: It would be great if you are providing a minimal working example to show what you want to achieve. It's hard to spot problems without seeing the whole script including libraries, etc..

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for [searching](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search), search type `user` specifies that the search value provided with the `q` parameter is to be treated as a name. You are not providing a name so the request fails. If you supply a more legitimate name, e.g. `John`, the request should succeed.

I don't know what algorithm Facebook uses to decide what is an acceptable name - it's possible to successfully search for "1", or "3", but not "375293253273" for some reason.

There is no search type for phone number, so I don't think it possible to search for phone numbers, and there would be privacy concerns with doing so.

Comment: How do you get access permission by user token to see his phone num? Is this possible?